# Posting JSONRPC command to pyBitmessage using CURL

Tags: c++11, curl, xml-rpc, json-rpc

I'm trying to post a command to the [pyBitmessage](https://www.bitmessage.org/wiki/API_Reference) XML-RPC server in c++ with [cpr](http://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/introduction.html) Curl implementation. Like this:

```
auto r = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{ "http://xxx:yyy@localhost:8442/" },
    cpr::Body{ "{\"jsonrpc\":\"1.0\",\"id\":1,\"method\":\"add\",\"params\":{\"a\":2,\"b\":3}}" },
    cpr::Header{ { "Content-Type", "application/json" } });
```

In return I have **r** returning a status_code 200 but with empty text result and this error value:

```
{code=INTERNAL_ERROR (4) message="transfer closed with 349 bytes remaining to read" }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, pyBitmessage is a regular XML-RPC and not a JSONish version of RPC like implemented with Bitcoind. So the right calling method is in pure XML:

```
auto r = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{ "http://xxx:yyy@127.0.0.1:8442/" },
cpr::Body{ "<methodCall><methodName>add</methodName><params><param><value><int>123</int></value></param><param><value><int>456</int></value></param></params></methodCall>" });
```